# Place css3 menu circles side by side

Tags: html, css

I have figured out most everything regarding these circles except how to put them side by side.  As is, one circle is on top of the other.  Things such as color, font, text position and such I have figured out or had help with.  But now, the circles being side by side  instead of top/bottom eludes me.  My ultimate goal is to have 4-5 circles all side by side.

```css
.ca-menu{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 500px;
}

.ca-menu li{
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border: 10px solid #f6f6f6;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: #fff;
    margin-right: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 125px;
    transition: all 400ms linear;
}

.ca-menu li:hover{
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border-color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
    color: #555;
    font-size: 60px;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    display: none;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="ca-icon"></span>
            <div class="ca-content">
                <h2 class="ca-main">testing</h2>
                <h3 class="ca-sub">testing2</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="ca-icon"></span>
            <div class="ca-content">
                 <h2 class="ca-main">testing3</h2>
                <h3 class="ca-sub">testing4</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `display:inline-block;` to ca-menu ?

Comment: That worked, but it put a huge gap between the two circles.  I'll work on figuring out how to eliminate that gap next.  Thanks so much!

Comment: it's the width of the same element, decrease it, or simply remove it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to take note:

1. All circle items should be inside one unique `ul`.
2. `display: inline-block;` is what makes element stay side by side.

It was not working in your case because you have set a width of 500px for the `ul` and the circles inside it were too big, so they had to go to the next line.

I removed this width and added `display: inline-block;` to each `li` item.

HTML:

```
<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="ca-icon"></span>
            <div class="ca-content">
                <h2 class="ca-main">testing</h2>
                <h3 class="ca-sub">testing2</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="ca-icon"></span>
            <div class="ca-content">
                 <h2 class="ca-main">testing3</h2>
                <h3 class="ca-sub">testing4</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.ca-menu{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.ca-menu li{
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border: 10px solid #f6f6f6;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    margin-right: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 125px;
    transition: all 400ms linear;
    display: inline-block;
}

.ca-menu li:hover{
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border-color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
    color: #555;
    font-size: 60px;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    display: none;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

And [here is a codepen of how it looks](https://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/PRemYK).

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is add to the .ca-menu a `display: inline`

```
.ca-menu{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 500px;
}
```